# Reverse string without reversing special characters using Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, reverse

I am unable to find problem in this code. I want to reverse the string without reversing special characters. So, if the string is `'ab#$cd!'` ,the output would be `'dc#$ba!'` the output I am getting is `'ab#$cd!'` (the same as input).

Kindly find the problem in the code.

```js
function isAlphabet(x) {

  if ((x >= 'A' && x <= 'Z') || (x >= 'a' && x <= 'z')) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}

function reverse() {
  var string1 = [];
  string1 = 'ab#$cd!'

  var n = string1.length;
  var r = n - 1;
  var i = 0;

  while (i < r) {

    if (!isAlphabet(string1[i])) {
      i++;
    } else if (!isAlphabet(string1[r])) {
      r--;
    } else {
      var temp;
      temp = string1[i];
      string1[i] = string1[r];
      string1[r] = temp;
      i++;
      r--;
    }
  }
  return string1;
}

console.log(reverse());
```

Comment: What do you expect when 'abcd#$ef!' ? In your example the number of letters before special chars are the same as the last ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify string in this way, strings are immutable in JavaScript

```js
var str = "abcdef";
console.log(str[1])
str[1] = "x"

console.log(str)
```

Change your string to array, modify array and then join it:

```js
var str = "abcdef", arr = str.split("");
console.log(arr[1])
arr[1] = "x"

console.log(arr.join(""))
```

Your example (consider renaming variables - I left original names):

```js
function isAlphabet(x) {

  if ((x >= 'A' && x <= 'Z') || (x >= 'a' && x <= 'z')) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}

function reverse() {
  var string1 = [];
  string1 = 'ab#$cd!'.split("")

  var n = string1.length;
  var r = n - 1;
  var i = 0;

  while (i < r) {

    if (!isAlphabet(string1[i])) {
      i++;
    } else if (!isAlphabet(string1[r])) {
      r--;
    } else {
      var temp;
      temp = string1[i];
      string1[i] = string1[r];
      string1[r] = temp;
      i++;
      r--;
    }
  }
  return string1.join("");
}

console.log(reverse());
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippit that uses split(), pop(), push() & reverse() methods.

```js
 function reverseString(str){
    var splitString, exclamationMark, reverseArray, joinArray;
    splitString = str.split("");
    exclamationMark = splitString.pop();
    reverseArray = splitString.reverse();
    reverseArray.push(exclamationMark);
    joinArray = reverseArray.join("");
    return joinArray;
 }
 console.log(reverseString("ab#$cd!"));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var str = "#hello$worl!d" var spclindx = []; var final = ''

var onlyalpha = str.match(/[a-z]|[A-Z]/g).reverse();

[...str].map((x, key) => { if (!x.match(/[a-z]/i)) { spclindx.push(key + '.' + x) } })

spclindx.map(y => { var sp = y.split('.'); console.log(sp) final = onlyalpha.splice(sp[0], 0, sp[1]) final = onlyalpha.join('') })

console.log(final)
```